# Map of an element in a group to the conjugation by g

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a group and suppose $g \in G$.

$\varphi:G\rightarrow Aut\left ( G \right )$

$g \mapsto i_{g}$

is a Homomorphism with image $Inn\left ( G \right )$
where $Inn\left ( G \right )=\left \{ i_{g}\mid g \in G \right \}$

The Kernel $Z\left ( G \right )=\left \{ x \in G \mid xg=gx, \forall x \in G \right \}$

> Recall:
>
> Let G be a group and suppose $g, h \in G.$
>
> The conjugation by g, $i_{g}$ is defined as
>
> $i_{g}:G\rightarrow G$
>
> $h\mapsto g^{-1}hg$

Could someone explain why $ker(\varphi)$ is the centre of a group G?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $i_{g}$ is the identity map on $G$, i.e. $g \in \ker(\varphi)$. Then $i_{g}(h) = g^{-1}hg = h$ for each $h \in G$, so $hg = gh$ for all $h \in G$. Hence, $g \in Z(G)$. On the other hand, suppose $g \in Z(G)$. Then $i_{g}(h) = g^{-1}hg = g^{-1}gh = h$, so $i_{g} = \mathrm{Id}_{G}$.

Comment: I have the idea. What is really confusing is notation; the sudden use of h from g.

Comment: Let $i_{g}$ be the identity map

The $ker\left ( \varphi \right )=\left \{ g \in G \mid \left ( g \right )\varphi=e=i_{g} \right \}$


$i_{g}\left ( g \right )=g^{-1}gg=g$

This implies $gg=gg$

Evidently, this is problematic. However, the switch of the g variables to the h variables is equally confusing.

Comment: Figured it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any $g$, saying $gx=xg$ is equivalent to saying $gxg^{-1}=x$. So if $g$ is in the center then $gxg^{-1}=x$ for all $x\in G$, i.e. $i_g$ is the identity map.